# Not able to read InputStream data in rest api

Tags: java, rest, inputstream, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I am passing file/img(form data) from my angular app to my rest api as a post method body.
But i am not able to read inputStream content.

My Rest api method:-

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void process(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream dataStream) throws IOException {

    this.writeToFile(dataStream, "src/main/resources/targetFile.jpg");
}

    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        byte[] image = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadedInputStream);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

        IOUtils.write(image, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

image array is always empty and hence empty file gets created in destination dir.
Anything wrong with the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can code rest service like this.

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    writeToFile(file, "src/main/resources/targetFile.jpg");
}
```

`writeToFile` method

```
private void writeToFile(MultipartFile file, String uploadedFileLocation) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation)));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Empty file");
    }
}
```